# How to use Eval() data in a method within a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval, repeater

I've written a method that checks and returns the status code of a URL. Then I used a repeater to grab rows from my db. What I'm trying to figure out is how to use the data returned in the repeater in a method called within the repeater. Here's the code for the ItemTemplate.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td><%# Eval("Bounce_from") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Bounce_to") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("is301") %></td>
        <td><% Response.Write(exist(Eval("Bounce_to")));  %></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

<% Response.Write(*exist(Eval("Bounce_to"))*);  %> is where I'm struggling. I've searched and can't find the answer. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction...thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the value in your `Eval` that you're trying to compare `Bounce_to` to...?

Comment: could you not write the following 
`Response.Write('<%# Eval("Bounce_to") != 0 %>'`);  for example..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as simple as

```
<td><%# exist(Eval("Bounce_to")) %></td>
```

This is assuming `exist` is available on the markup (it should at least protected page method) and accepts `object` as an input argument since Eval returns object.

Basically `<%# %>` runs whatever code is inside it in data binding context (thus Eval is available) and outputs the final value to the markup.

Comment: I'm an idiot...didn't cast as a string on the first pass...always trying to look for complex solutions to simple problems.

 <td><%# exist((string)Eval("Bounce_to"))  %></td>

Thanks!

Comment: @GeekInTheBox You should really just use `ToString()` rather than explicit, mostly because if it fails to cast you'll receive a massive error on your page.  Which will impede your users / ux drastically.

Comment: @Andrei Technically your code isn't valid, unless `Exist` actually is a valid parameter type.  Which under most circumstances, it isn't.  So you may want to clarify that in your answer.

Comment: @Greg, sorry, what exactly do you mean? What parameter type? [Eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an `object`. So `exist` has to be a protected page class method (to be accessible from the markup) and has to accept one parameter of type object for the code in the answer to work. I think this all is clear enough in the answer itself. `exist` itself can return whatever it wants, it will be safely interpreted as a string. So what is this `valid parameter type` that you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing your *Repeater* in entirety, it will be difficult to troubleshoot.  But a working example, that may help you solve your issue.

```
<asp:Repeater Id="rpCustomer" runat="server" DataSourceId="dsCustomer">
     <ItemTemplate>

     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The important part of the repeater, is the `DataSourceId`.  You want to ensure it is correctly configured and indeed pulling the data out of the database.

The second part, is almost as if your attempting to call a method for the `Eval()`.  That way you can modify the data, at any given point as the data source is iterating.

```
<!-- An Example -->
<%# Truncate(Eval("Description").ToString()) %>
```

So, in my case `Truncate` would be on the code behind like a traditional method:

```
protected string Truncate(string source)
{
     // Logic and Include valid Data Return
}
```

This will allow quick manipulation of data being pulled out of the database before it is displayed within the *View State*.

```
<!-- Final Result: -->
    <asp:Repeater Id="rpCustomer" runat="server" DataSourceId="dsCustomer">
         <ItemTemplate>
               <%# Truncate(Eval("Description").ToString()) %>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```